# why say.py in sound_play package cannot be used with roslaunch?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rospy, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

say.py works if it come with rosrun.
I mean at first I have launched a launch file containing:

```
<node pkg="sound_play" type="soundplay_node.py" name="sound_play" output="screen"/>
```

(consider its name is first.launch)

and then in another terminal I have run:

rosrun mypackage say.py

---

but how can I launch say.py with a launch file?
I have say.py inside "mypackage" and a launch file(named second.launch) like this:

```
<node pkg="mypackage" type="say.py" name="say" output="screen"/>
```

but it got some errors in the terminal in which i have launched first.luanch:

```
sound: -3
command: 1
volume: 1.0
arg: __name:=say
arg2: __log:=/home/mostafa/.ros/log/53b70204-7c11-11e7-b929-acbc32787137/say-1.log
SIOD ERROR: unbound variable : __log:=/home/mostafa/.ros/log/53b70204-7c11-11e7-b929-acbc32787137/say-1.log
[ERROR] [1502179966.421258]: Sound synthesis failed. Is festival installed? Is a festival voice installed? Try running "rosdep satisfy sound_play|sh". Refer to http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play/Troubleshooting
[ERROR] [1502179966.421695]: Exception in callback: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'command'
```

and a warning in the terminal of second.launch:

```
Saying: __name:=say
Voice: __log:=/home/mostafa/.ros/log/53b70204-7c11-11e7-b929-acbc32787137/say-1.log
Volume: 1.0
[WARN] [1502179964.306939]: Sound command issued, but no node is subscribed to the topic. Perhaps you forgot to run soundplay_node.py?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268265/why-say.py-in-sound_play-package-cannot-be-used-with-roslaunch?/) by [s_mostafa_a](https://answers.ros.org/users/31283/s_mostafa_a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because script `say.py` (must be written to be a standalone python script and hence) accepts [sysargs](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/blob/1931af14cabf009c6d2b61a556c70f1c63a4b0d5/sound_play/scripts/say.py#L57). When `say.py` is launched with roslaunch, addition sysargs are passed to the script and `__name:=say` becomes the `sys.argv[1]`.

The solution for this is to modify the `say.py` to accept `rosparam`.

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2017-08-09**:
Possibly helpful: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Accessing_your_command-line_arguments